# BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress blocking call

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

How to make `BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress` wait for ProgressChanged event to complete?

I have an app that processes queue in `BackgroundWorker_DoWork` and displays videos as new files are received.

`ReportProgress` is asynchronous, so multiple calls to it result in multiple forms with videos stack up on the screen, instead of appearing one by one.

Of course, I could call the form's `ShowDialog()` directly from `DoWork`, but the form is using Windows Media Player control, which works only from the GUI thread.

So again, how to wait for `ReportProgress` to complete when calling it from `DoWork`?

Comment: What are you doing in the ProgressChanged event handler? Displaying a dialog window? You could block your DoWork event handler until you are finished with whatever you are doing in your ReportProgress event handler by moving the code in the latter into a call to Dispatcher.Invoke.

Comment: `ProgressChanged ` isn't asynchronous. The `ProgressChanged ` event is raised in the *UI* thread. It *has* to, in order to be able to modify any controls or show any dialog boxes. That's not a problem of BGW

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That's not true. This is written in MSDN: "The call to the ReportProgress method is asynchronous and returns immediately." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka89zff4(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2

Comment: @OfirWinegarten should have said `ProgressChanged`. I meant the event has to be raised in the UI thread

Comment: @SharpAffair post your code please. If you want to display notifications for a lot of files, opening multiple dialog boxes is *not* a good idea anyway. It's better to modify the title, contents of the dialog box and displaying a progress bar

Comment: You'd use AutoResetEvent.  Call its WaitOne() method after ReportProgress, Set() in the ProgressChanged event handler.  Bad idea however, the user loses control over the program and can't stop it anymore.  Consider creating a playlist.

Comment: @HansPassant that worked perfectly. Why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: Because it is a bad idea and I don't know what you did about it.  Just share what you came up with in your own post.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should show your videos in BackgroundWorkerCompleted. I Your Dowork you can add your videos to a List, and then when all Work is done, show them one by one.